# How to shift a bits in a Ushort 16 bit integer in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, 16-bit, uint

I have a 16 bit unsigned integer and its values are like this:

```
byte_val1 = 1000000000000001
```

From this I need to right shift this and make it like this:

```
  1100000000000000
```

I have done this:

```
 byte_val1 = byte_val1 >> 1
```

and getting `byte_val1 = 100000000000000`.

After that I did

```
  byte_val1 = byte_val1 Or &H80
```

but I didn't get the desired result... Instead I got `100000010000000`.

So what should I do to get that result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it right this time. I did this:

```
byte_val1 = byte_val1 >> 1

byte_val1 = byte_val1 Or &H8000
```

And it worked.

Comment: This would always append 1 to the left. What if your right-most bit is 0? You may want to use mask instead of `&H8000`, which is initially equal to `byte_val1 And &H8000`. Then do `byte_val1 = byte_val1 Or mask`.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using unsigned data type, the sign bit propagation is not happening. Use a signed integer for the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

What you appear to actually want is to *rotate* the bits, not shift them:

```
Module Module1

    Function RORUInt16(n As UInt16, r As Integer) As UInt16
        ' ensure number of places to shift is valid
        r = r And 15
        If r = 0 Then
            ' nothing to do
            Return n
        End If

        ' get bits from RHS
        Dim RHS = Convert.ToUInt16(n And ((2 << r) - 1))
        ' shift the original bits right (loses the RHS saved previously)
        Dim rb = Convert.ToUInt16(n >> r)
        ' put back the lost bits on the LHS
        rb = Convert.ToUInt16(rb Or (RHS << (16 - r)))
        Return rb
    End Function

    Sub Main()

        Dim b1 As UInt16 = Convert.ToUInt16("0000001000000111", 2)

        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(b1, 2).PadLeft(16, "0"c))
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(RORUInt16(b1, 1), 2).PadLeft(16, "0"c))
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```